# How to create / manipulate CRC errors

Tags: embedded, usb, transfer, crc

I'm implementing a microprocessor as a USB device. It is using an Isochronous Transfer. Now i want to test the Isochronous Transfer reliability, so i have set up an interrupt that interrupts when an CRC error occurs.

I want to test if the CRC error interrupt is working, so does anyone know how to create a CRC error? maybe there is some software, or some hardware work around?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if your code does the correct error handling simply set the CRC error interrupt request flag by software.

If you want to check if your USB chip detects CRC errors correctly you will have to generate a real CRC error on bus. As far as I know there are USB bus analyzers (expensive) that can do this.
Or try to disturb the USB signals by connecting a resistor between D-/D+ temporarily. But this will cause any errors, maybe CRC errors too.

Comment: I tried briefly connecting a resistor between D+ and D-, this caused the processor to reset, and it didn't detect any CRC errors. 
I tried with the an USB Analyzer (USB Explorer 200 from Ellisys), but it couldnt generate the errors, or edit any of the content on the bus while running.